# Window.onload me carga la pagina muchas veces

Tags: php, funciones

Hola buenas noches o tardes soy facundo estoy en busca de una solución para la función window.onload o alguna otra solución con otro código, explico estoy haciendo un proyecto de agendas de turnos y tengo un temita ahí con el submit, bueno el error que no entiendo es que al hacer la función:

```
        <script>

              window.onload = function(){
                document.getElementById("form1").submit();
                
              }

          </script>
```

Esta función hace todo bien pero no se porque empieza a cargar la pagina 1 y otra ves(infinitas veces) y no tengo la menor idea de porque, alguien me echa una mano???

Form:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="es">
 <head>
       <meta charset="UTF-8">
       <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos.css">
<title>Reserva Turnos</title>
<script>

              window.onload = function(e){
                document.getElementById("pepe").submit();
                e.preventDefault();
              }

</script>
    </head>
   <body>
     <?php include 'navbar.php' ?> 
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
      <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="nav-home-tab">
<div class="container bg-white mt-3">
<h2 class="text-center">Turnos Existentes</h2>


          <form id="form1" action="#" method="POST">
               <div class="col-lg-7 col-4 mt-4">
                 <div class="d-flex flex-lg-row flex-column justify- 
       content-lg-between justify-content-center align-items-lg-end 
                    align-items- 
                    start form-group">
        
            
            <label for="Fecha">Fecha de Hoy:
                    <input class="form-control mr-3" type="date"  name="Fecha" id="fecha" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d") ?>" required>
            </label>

            <label for="Sucursal">Sucursal
            <select  class="form-select" name="Sucursal_turno" id="Sucursal_turno" required> 
            <?php foreach($sucursal as $dato2){
              if(isset($_POST["Sucursal_turno"]) && $_POST["Sucursal_turno"]==$dato2->NOMBRE_SUCURSAL)
              echo '<option value="'.$dato2->NOMBRE_SUCURSAL.'" selected>'.$dato2->NOMBRE_SUCURSAL.' </option>';
            else
             echo '<option value="'.$dato2->NOMBRE_SUCURSAL.'">'.$dato2->NOMBRE_SUCURSAL.' </option>'; ?>
              
              <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </label>
                 
            <label for="profesional">Profesional
            <select class="form-select" name="Usuario_truno" id="Usuario_truno" required>
            <?php foreach($usuario as $dato3){
              if(isset($_POST["Usuario_truno"]) && $_POST["Usuario_truno"]==$dato3->USUARIO)
              echo '<option value="'.$dato3->USUARIO.'" selected>'.$dato3->USUARIO.' </option>';
   else
                   echo '<option value="'.$dato3->USUARIO.'">'.$dato3->USUARIO.' </option>';
              ?>
           
            <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </label>
            <input class="btn btn-dark mt-lg-0 mt-3" type="submit" 
             id="filtar" value="Mostrar Datos" name="filtar">
            </div>
</div>

           
</form>
```

Hola buenas noches o tardes soy facundo estoy en busca de una solución para la función window.onload o alguna otra solución con otro código, explico estoy haciendo un proyecto de agendas de turnos y tengo un temita ahí con el submit, bueno el error que no entiendo es que al hacer la función:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es asi:  `value="<?= (isset($_POST['Fecha'])? $_POST['Fecha'] : date("Y-m-d")); ?>"`

Comment: De hecho aun podria ser mas corto y funcionaria igual, asi:  `value="<?= $_POST['Fecha']? $_POST['Fecha'] : date("Y-m-d"); ?>"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quita el window.onload de arriba, todo el script.
Y pon esto justo despues del `</form>`

```
<?php 
  if(!isset($_POST["Sucursal_turno"]) and !isset($_POST["Usuario_truno"])) {
      ?>
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById("form1").submit();
    }
</script>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Y prueba a ver si te funciona.

De esta forma lo que hacemos es comprobar que aún no se ha ejecutado el formulario, mirando si hay los valores POST pasados, y forzamos su ejecución por primera vez. Y al ejecutarse esta primera vez si que pasará los valores POST y no volverá a ejecutarse automáticamente de nuevo.

Comment: La verdad que sos un genio, quedo funcionando todo good